# Display records from Database one at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

**Can anyone tell me how to retrieve records from database one at a time.**

*I am attaching my code here:*

Let me explain the code..

There is a table named "cquest" (containing some questions) in database with a field named "question" and options are in field "opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4".

*The below code display all the questions stored in the table into the screen.*

**My problem is here:
I want to display the questions one by one. Like when we click the next button it will display the next question and so until all the records are displayed.**

*Help me out with the main logic I should use to implement it. Or help me with the script.*

````
           $servername = "localhost";
           $username = "root";
           $password = "";
           $dbname = "quiz";
           $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
           if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

           $sql = "SELECT * FROM cquest";
           $result = $conn->query($sql);
           if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<div class='row'>";
                echo "<div class='col-md-6 mb-6'>";
                echo "<div class='card shadow border-0 h-100'>";
                echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                echo "<h5 class='dark-text'>".$row['question']."</h5>";
                echo "<div class='bg-light'>";
                echo "<code class='dark-text'>".$row['ccode']."</code>";
              echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='custom-control custom-radio'>";
                      echo "<input type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample1'  name='ans' value='a' checked>";
                      echo "<label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample1>".$row["opt1"]."</label></br>";
                      echo "</div>";
                      echo "<div class='custom-control custom-radio'>";
                      echo "<input type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample2'  name='ans' value='b'>";
                      echo "<label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample2>".$row["opt2"]."</label></br>";
                      echo "</div>";
                      echo "<div class='custom-control custom-radio'>";
                      echo "<input type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample3'  name='ans' value='c'>";
                      echo "<label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample3>".$row["opt3"]."</label></br>";
                      echo "</div>";
                      echo "<div class='custom-control custom-radio'>";
                      echo "<input  type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample4' name='ans' value='d'>";
                      echo "<label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample4>".$row["opt4"]."</label></br>";
                      echo "</div>";
                      echo "<button name=submit class=next>NEXT</button>";
                      echo "</div>";
                      echo "</div>";
                      echo "</div>";
                      echo "</div>";

            }
            }
           }
           else {
            echo "Currently Unavailable";
           }
$conn->close();
?>```
````

Comment: Your question table should have an column for successor (next question). The HTML Form should send the question ID along, so you can identify a successor of an answered question.

Comment: Hope it's help you - https://technopoints.co.in/create-simple-quiz-using-php-mysql

Comment: You're looking for what is called "pagination".

Comment: Sorry, but writing "echo ... echo ... echo ... echo ..." makes your code a little bit ugly. You should mix your HTML code blocks with php code blocks or even better, using MVC platform for your project.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to put all the questions the page and hide all except the first one and then use javascript/jQuery to show the next question when you click the next button.

In the code below I have added the logic and javascript needed.

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "quiz";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cquest";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //set up a count to help track waht record we are up to. 0 = first record 
        $count = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $style = ""; //set style to blank

        if($count > 0 ){ //if its not the first question, add styling to hide the question
            $style = " style='display:none;'";
        }

        echo "
            <div class='row question-container' ".$style.">"; // <-- Styling added to this line if it not the first question

        echo"   <div class='col-md-6 mb-6'>
                    <div class='card shadow border-0 h-100'>
                        <div class='card-body'>
                            <h5 class='dark-text'>".$row['question']."</h5>
                            <div class='bg-light'>
                                <code class='dark-text'>".$row['ccode']."</code>
                            </div>
                            <div class='custom-control custom-radio'>
                                <input type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample1'  name='ans' value='a' checked>
                                <label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample1>".$row["opt1"]."</label></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class='custom-control custom-radio'>
                                <input type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample2'  name='ans' value='b'>
                                <label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample2>".$row["opt2"]."</label></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class='custom-control custom-radio'>
                                <input type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample3'  name='ans' value='c'>
                                <label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample3>".$row["opt3"]."</label></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class='custom-control custom-radio'>
                                <input  type='radio' class='custom-control-input' id='defaultGroupExample4' name='ans' value='d'>
                                <label class='custom-control-label' for=defaultGroupExample4>".$row["opt4"]."</label></br>
                            </div>
                            <button name='submit' class='next'>NEXT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ";
        $count++; //increment the counter

    }// End While

    } else {
        echo "Currently Unavailable";
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
<!-- include jQuery -->
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
//Set event handler for next buttons
$(".next").on("click",function(){
    hide_current_question($(this)); //hide current question
    show_next_question($(this)); //show the next question
});

function hide_current_question(element){
    //find the parent with class of 'question-container' and hide it;
    element.closest(".question-container").hide();
}

function show_next_question(element){
    //find the parent with class of 'question-container' and then show the next element with class of 'question-container' 
    element.closest(".question-container").next(".question-container").show();
}

function show_previous_question(element){
    //find the parent with class of 'question-container' and then show the previous element with class of 'question-container' 
    element.closest(".question-container").previous(".question-container").show();
}
</script>
<!-- END -->
```

Key Changes:

- Added a class 'question-container' to the outer most div for each question
- Added a counter for tacking what question you are up to in the for loop.
- <s>Added [ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) logic to set the styling thats used to hide questions that are not the first question</s>
- Added if statement logic to set the styling thats used to hide questions that are not the first question
- Included jQuery Library
- Added event handler logic for next button that shows the next question and hides the previous.
- Added javaScript functions for easier readability

If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: I couldn't understand where to use ternary operator and how to hide the previous question. If try to hide it entire page is empty

Comment: @JeevaSaravanan I have removed the ternary and replaced it with standard if logic and left a comment where the styling gets applied. I also created some new javaScript functions to help hide the previous question. The javaScript should be easier to understand now.

Comment: But radio button is not working(like unable to get answer) from question 2, if i add bootstrap links . @RyDog

Comment: @JeevaSaravanan can you please update your question with any problems you have it will be easier to solve them that way. tag me once you have updated it.